# Convert a string into array with keys

Tags: php, arrays, string, key

I have a string variable :

```
$asd = '[asd] => 0, [mogh] => 1,[for] => 3 ';
```

I want to convert it into and array with keys.  This is what I want:

```
$array['asd'] = 0
$array['mogh'] = 1
$array['for'] = 3
```

Comment: Why?  Where are you getting this string?

Comment: Is the string a fixed format? It would be much easier to use json_decode and specify the string as `$asd='{"asd":0,"mogh":1,"for":3}';` then all you need to do is call json_decode($asd,true); (the second argument makes it return an array instead of an object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another format such as JSON if you are constructing this, or even `var_export()` depending on your needs, however if you have no choice:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)\] => (\d+)/', $asd, $matches);
$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Or you could clean it up and turn it into a query string to parse:

```
echo $asd = str_replace(array('[',']',' ','=>',','), array('','','','=','&'), $asd);
parse_str($asd, $array);
```

Comment: as for you second approach which emulates query string parsing: we know that there could be an array like `ab[]=1&ab[]=2&...` , that will be broken by replacement. But, of course, my remark concerns a more complex cases ...

Comment: so [asd] => 0, [mogh] => 1,[for] => 3 will be asd=0 & mogh=1&for=3

Comment: Yes `asd=0&mogh=1&for=3`. Lemme guess, that was what you really wanted?

Comment: Yes i just wanted a way to organize array data as a string , thanks

Comment: `json_encode()` would probably be best.